# Get muiltiple items from list (two or more non consecutive)

Tags: c#, list

I searched the web for this very simple question but I didn´t find a simple answer.

Tried next lines with error but I´d like to know if there is a simplest way.

```
List<string> listaStr = new List<string> {"cero","uno","dos","tres","cuatro"};
List<int> indices = new List<int> {0,4};
var valores = new List<object>();

foreach (var i in indices)
{
valores.Add(listaStr[i]);
}

foreach (var i in valores)
{
Console.WriteLine(valores[i]);
}
```

Expecting as output: "cero","cuatro" in a new list (valores)

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following code and it seems to work:

```
    List<string> listaStr = new List<string> {"cero","uno","dos","tres","cuatro"};
    List<int> indices = new List<int> {0,4};
    var selectedStrings = new List<object>();
    
    foreach(var index in indices)
    {
        selectedStrings.Add(listaStr[index]);
    }
    
    foreach(var value in selectedStrings)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
```

Make sure you have all the required imports set above:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

If the error still persists I will come back and try to answer again.

I've edited the code, please have a look.

Comment: The error is can´t convert from object to int. 
I got the lines with writeline too but I need the values into a list to a next operation

Comment: @jptrujillol I found out what your mistake was: in the second foreach, you tried accessing the list elements by index, but the foreach loop already had the object you are iterating in the i variable. So instead of selectedStrings[i], you should simply print the "i" variable, which is your element. My answer handles that more explicitly.

Comment: Thank you Gabriel for the additional explanation.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have `selectedStrings` typed as `new List<string>()` ?

Comment: it´s ok Gabriel, just an example. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Bouke While I agree that it would be better to have it as a list of strings, in the provided example OP used a list of objects, so I assumed he might need the list as a list of objects and I did not modify that

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Last loop is just to display the items in the resulting list.

```
var listaStr = new List<string> { "cero", "uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro" };
var indices = new List<int> { 0, 4 };
var selectedStrings = new List<string>();

foreach (var i in indices)
{
    selectedStrings.Add(listaStr[i]);
}

foreach (var s in selectedStrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did the same but I need the items in a new list for a next operation.

Comment: Will update code accordingly.

Comment: Just updated the code snippet.

Comment: Also provided an alternative solution using LINQ in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative the result can be obtained by using a LINQ expression. This is harder to read and probably a bit slower when using a lot of strings however.

```
var listaStr = new List<string> { "cero", "uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro" };
var indices = new List<int> { 0, 4 };

var selectedStrings = listaStr.Where(x => indices.Contains(listaStr.IndexOf(x))).ToList();

foreach (var s in selectedStrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: Me encanta. Thank you a lot. I´m using it and soon I hope to be able to understand that line better. Studying from now...

Answer (score 0):

Variation inspired on @Bouke´s answer

```
var listaStr = new List<string> { "cero", "uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro" };
var indices = new List<int> { 0, 4 };

var selectedStrings = listaStr.Where((x,i) => indices.Contains(i)).ToList();

foreach (var s in selectedStrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).